# Need a Formula/Macro/VBA that copies/moves data within a sheet based on another cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need some Excel help here. I need some kind of formula (rather not use a macro or VBA unless I have to) that will copy a dollar amount in one cell to another cell based on the number (number of days) in another cell. For example, if the company received $5,000 on Jan 5th and payment terms are 5 days, then I need to copy that $5,000 payment and display it in a calendar 5 business days from when it was received (Jan 12th). Maybe I need some kind of back-up sheet with more formulas or something. Does that make sense? I've included an image below of what the formula should do. Let me know if you need any more details. Thanks!

[image]

EDIT: Full image of columns and rows.
[Revised formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVhDG.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that:

- `A1` is the cell containing the Average Term (Days)
- Row 2 has the Sales data
- Row 3 has the Direct Cash Flow data

Try this in row 3:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN() - $A$1))
```

The first cells of row 3 may output `#VALUE` because `COLUMN() - $A$1` may become negative. Solve with

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN() - $A$1)), "")
```

---

Info about the [INDIRECT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) and [ADDRESS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/address-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89) functions.

---

EDIT: Answer to Greene1999's comment

To prevent the formula from fetching data outside of the table you could limit the column index:

```
=IF(COLUMN - $A$1 < 1, "", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2, COLUMN() - $A$1)))
```

Of course you would replace 1 by whichever row the beginning of the table is.

The `IFERROR` function should not be necessary as the formula should never reach negative indexes.

Comment: Thank you! That formula is working great and I think it's a good start, but there are a couple issues that will need to be resolved. First, the formula is carrying cell contents that don't need to carried, such as the customer name and blank cells. I only need the sales numbers moved. Also, collections of cash payments (the lower section) cannot land on a weekend. I inserted those columns so I could follow the calendar, but sales and collections can only be made on weekdays. How can this be fixed?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment your answer, but don't ask questions by posting an answer. You can either edit your original question or post comments!

Comment: I edited my answer to avoid the formula fetching cells outside the data table.

Comment: I tried using the revised formula and it resulted in a #NAME? error. I have included a full image of the rows and columns in my original question so you can use the correct cell references. Also, what could be added in this formula or another formula to prevent collections from landing on gray cells, which are weekends? You'll notice I am using the Actual Days in column D instead of column C because col C is business days and col D is real calendar days (business days +2). Let me know how you would redesign this. Thanks!